# DIVS / WEBSITE NOT FILLING ENTIRE SCREEN ON MOBILE

Tags: mobile, width, screen, viewport

im having trouble getting my website to fill the entire screen on mobile devices.

My meta tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and the css

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
width: 100% ;
}
```

http://www.girlsskateaustralia.com

anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine on mobile IE but some browsers might be picky about the `initial scale` value; this is what I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```